# Is using composition to leverage inheritance from Java abstract collections classes bad practice?

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, abstract, composition

A lot of times I find myself (what appears to be) combining composition and inheritance when inheriting from abstract collection classes and I can't help but feel like it's *technically* conflicting design paradigms while I do it.

```java
/** Custom String List implementation */
public class MyStringList extends AbstractList<String>
{
    private final AbstractList<String> _myStringList;

    public MyStringList()
    {
        this._myStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public MyStringList(Collection<String> stringCollection)
    {
        if (stringCollection.contains(null))
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("Null values not permitted in MyStringList");
        }
        else
        {
            this._myStringList = new ArrayList<String>(stringCollection);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String get(int index)
    {
        return this._myStringList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return this._myStringList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String set(int index, String aString)
    {
        ++this.modCount;
        return this._myStringList.set(index, Objects.requireNonNull(aString));
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, String aString)
    {
        ++this.modCount;
        this._myStringList.add(index, Objects.requireNonNull(aString));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(String aString)
    {
        ++this.modCount;
        return this._myStringList.add(Objects.requireNonNull(aString));
    }

    @Override
    public String remove(int index)
    {
        ++this.modCount;
        return this._myStringList.remove(index);
    }

    // Method to make this list implementation distinct from ArrayList for the sake of
    // this StackOverflow question example
    public String[] getNumericContaining()
    {
        return this._myStringList.stream()
                                 .filter(aString -> aString.codePoints().anyMatch(Character::isDigit))
                                 .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    // Another method to make this list implementation distinct from ArrayList for
    // the sake of this StackOverflow question example
    public String[] getUpperCaseContaining()
    {
        return this._myStringList.stream()
                                 .filter(aString -> aString.codePoints().anyMatch(Character::isUpperCase))
                                 .toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```

Is this design of having an internal abstract collection object being the backing object (composition) of the class this object inherits from (inheritance) considered the "correct" way of leveraging the various abstract collection classes defined in the java.util package?

Comment: The only reason you should use those abstract collections is if you were to create a new kind of collection altogether (e.g. "linked" list, or "array" list except they already exist). You're merely creating a new *flavor* which can easily be done with composition alone.

Comment: "correct" always depends on the requirements, you could aswell just `extends ArrayList<String>` if you don't have any additional logic

Comment: @Kayaman Any chance you could elaborate on (or link to an explanation) of what the difference is between "kind" and "flavor"?

Comment: @Lino I updated the code snippet example so `null` values aren't permitted so extending `ArrayList<String>` would violate ArrayList's implementation.

Comment: Your example class here is just a flavor of `ArrayList<String>`, built in an overly complex way. Different *kinds* of lists are for example `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, etc. which differ significantly in their internal design. Since you're creating a flavor of `ArrayList<String>`, extending it would be a lot easier as Lino said. Or you could use a regular list and extract the extra behaviour to its encapsulating class.

Comment: @Kayaman I appreciate the feedback from both you and @Lino! Your references to the other concrete collection classes and explanation helps! Thanks! Any chance you could combine your first comment and then last comment into an answer so I can flag it as an answer? I'm just seeing now you also reference concrete classes in your first answer as well. Thanks for humoring me with further explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're combining things unnecessarily. If you want to have what you have in the example, go with Lino's suggestion:

```
public class MyStringList extends ArrayList<String> {

    public String[] getNumericContaining() {
        return this.stream()
                   .filter(aString -> aString.codePoints().anyMatch(Character::isDigit))
                   .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    public String[] getUpperCaseContaining() {
        return this.stream()
                   .filter(aString -> aString.codePoints().anyMatch(Character::isUpperCase))
                   .toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```

however many times a regular `List<String>` is all you need, since you can extract extra behaviour to the class that encapsulates the list, e.g.

```
public class MySomeService {
    
    // This could be passed in, loaded from somewhere, etc.
    private List<String> foo;

    public void serviceMethod() {
        doSomething();
        String[] numbers = getNumericContaining();
        doSomethingElse(numbers);
    }

    // The previous methods
    private String[] getNumericContaining() {
        foo.stream(). // and so on
}
```

It depends on whether your list really is a class in its own right, or whether it's just a special flavor that you need at some point. If it's the first, it may deserve its own class, if it's the latter, it doesn't.

Finally, even though OOP tells you to put data and behaviour in the same place, sometimes it makes sense to keep them in different places, so a method or a function can be used. Just pass the list as a parameter, and it'll work for all `Collection` classes not just your special one.